# BX-Slider active class not working when using with pagerCustom which is also slider

Tags: jquery, bxslider

BX-Slider active class not working when using with pagerCustom. Pager is also slider with active class which is with red border. Any idea how to fix it?

Html:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/me_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
<div id="bx-pager">
  <a data-slide-index="0" href=""><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg" width="100" /></a>
  <a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/me_trees.jpg" width="100" /></a>
  <a data-slide-index="2" href=""><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/houses.jpg" width="100" /></a>
  <a data-slide-index="3" href=""><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" width="100" /></a>
  <a data-slide-index="4" href=""><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg" width="100" /></a>
  <a data-slide-index="5" href=""><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" width="100" /></a>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  pagerCustom: '#bx-pager'
});

$('#bx-pager').bxSlider({
  mode: 'horizontal',
  pager: false
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w259nfeu/

Comment: Can you be specific as to what doesn't work? In your demo, both sliders function.

Comment: On second slider (which is pager for first slider) click next and when click on small image, red border should be where, but its not. Active class not working on second slider when you choose other photos. Question is how to fix it?

Comment: bxSlider makes clones of the slides so that the active slide is tracking active off canvas I don't think tracking active is actually tracking current slide. At least this seems true when using a pager as a slider. Active is an internal reference. Are you trying to sync both sliders to move? I have a modified version of your demo. I'll post it if your'e interested.

Comment: Show me your version, would be great to sync both sliders to move.

Answer (score 1):

The top slider has no controls, it's movement is tied into the second slider/pager. The second slider looked weird with only one slide, so I made it a carousel with 3 slides moving one at a time. The rotation is:

- Every click on an arrow advances both sliders in the same direction.
- Every 6 clicks in one direction will cause the top slider to return to the same slide as the second slider's middle slide.
- A click on one of the second slider's slide will make the first slider jump to the corresponding slide.

For some reason, the stack snippet is having DNS issues, so take a look at the

**Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/IytWudzqeXyYMzwIQnbA?p=preview**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SO35203571</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css" />
  <style>
    #bx-pager {
      left: 25px;
    }
    .bx-wrapper a.active {
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
    .bx-controls-direction a {
      top: -100% !important;
    }
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
      <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/me_trees.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/houses.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="bx-pager">
    <a data-slide-index="0" href="">
      <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg" width="100" />
    </a>
    <a data-slide-index="1" href="">
      <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/me_trees.jpg" width="100" />
    </a>
    <a data-slide-index="2" href="">
      <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/houses.jpg" width="100" />
    </a>
    <a data-slide-index="3" href="">
      <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" width="100" />
    </a>
    <a data-slide-index="4" href="">
      <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg" width="100" />
    </a>
    <a data-slide-index="5" href="">
      <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" width="100" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {

      var bx = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        pagerCustom: '#bx-pager',
        controls: false
      });

      var cx = $('#bx-pager').bxSlider({
        mode: 'horizontal',
        maxSlides: 3,
        minSlides: 3,
        moveSlides: 1,
        slideWidth: 275,
        slideMargin: 40,
        pager: false,
        onSlideBefore: bxMove
      });

      function bxMove($ele, from, to) {
        var idx = parseInt(to, 10) - 1;
        bx.goToSlide(idx);
      }

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```